# Chainer: Cannot deserialize

Tags: python, chainer

Using chainer, I have model learn ptb text. Then, serialized model and optimizer. However, I cannot deserialize them.

If you know why please tell me.

```
import chainer
from chainer import serializers

 # codes used for serializing
# serializers.save_hdf5('rnnlm.model', model)
# serializers.save_hdf5('rnnlm.state', optimizer):

# codes for deserializing
model = serializers.load_hdf5('rnnlm.model', model)
optimizer  = serializers.load_hdf5('rnnlm.state', optimizer)
# model => None
# optimizer => None
```

Comment: This looks a bit weird `model = serializers.load_hdf5('rnnlm.model', model)`. Does it work if you just do `serializers.load_hdf5('rnnlm.model', model)` i.e. without capturing the return value (which is probably `None`).

Answer (score 1):

The model and optimizer should be created firstly. load_hdf5 works like replacing the parameters of your existing model rather than creating new model for you.